# Как получить изображение из потока?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Отправляю Http запрос к api для получения изображения:

```
Url = $"http://mini.s-shot.ru/1024/1000/png/?{Url}";            
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var image = stream.ReadToEnd();
}
```

В каком формате данных хранить изображение и как его принимать?

Comment: Вы делаете неправильно. StreamReader читает строку, то есть портит бинарные данные.

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понимаю, вопрос задан не совсем коректно, но интересует именно следующий код:

```
string webPath = "someUrl"

if (webPath != string.Empty)
{
    try
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest request =
            System.Net.WebRequest.Create(webPath);

        System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        Bitmap bitmapImg = new Bitmap(responseStream);

        return bitmapImg;
    }
    catch (System.Net.WebException)
    {
    }
}

return new Bitmap(1,1);
```